# How to import a component and props type alias simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

```
export type PublicOrPrivateProps = {
  publicOrPrivate: PublicOrPrivateT
};

export default ({ publicOrPrivate }: PublicOrPrivateProps) => <Box>{publicOrPrivate}</Box>;
```

And I'm trying to import like this:

```
import type PublicOrPrivate, { PublicOrPrivateProps } from 'components/newrfq/reviewRFQ/PublicOrPrivate';
```

But it fails with the following error:

> type referenced from value position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write `type` inside the list of names, e.g.

```
import PublicOrPrivate, { type PublicOrPrivateProps } from 'components/newrfq/reviewRFQ/PublicOrPrivate';
```

This syntax was added in Flow 0.38.0.